# How can I speed up the nested loops in my program?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, optimization, multiprocessing

Im working on a slot machine simulator. [Code](https://gist.github.com/zeratoss/156b07f2cb40f97eaefd156ddd6aeb2c)

The heart of the program is a nested loop like this:

```
import pandas

for universe in range(10000):
    for spins in range(50000):
        win = paytable.Multiplier.sample(weights=paytable.Probability)
        result.append(win)
```

Universes are the amount of times the wagering process should be simulated.

Spins are the amount of spins played in each universe.

The program makes a weighted choice from a pandas dataframe to determine if a spin won and how much.

The problem is that I need to execute all these operations  to get a large enough sample size and this gets **really** slow.

I have read some stuff about multiprocessing and vectorization but I have no idea how applicable this is and where to start.

Comment: `np.random.choice(paytable.Mutiplier, p=paytable.Probability, shape=(10000,50000))`?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I assume that would just grab all the values at once? Could you explain what shape = does?

Answer (score 0):

You can parallelize your CPU work depending on how many cores you have. Let's say you have 8

```
import threading
import pandas

pool_semaphore = threading.BoundedSemaphore(value=8)

## Define a wrapper function that makes clear the passing of the argument and appends to some list 'result' that I will create later.
def awrapper(myarg):
    result.append(paytable.Multiplier.sample(weights = myarg))

threads = []
result = []

for universe in range(10000):
    for spins in range(50000):
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=awrapper, args=(paytable.Probability,)))
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            threads[-1].start()
            print(threading.active_count())
        except:
            time.sleep(1)
            print('oops. Error')
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Now. If the function patytable.Multiplier.sample is simple enough. You can perhaps parallelize in GPU. But that's a whole different thing.